# changing a permutation into combinations (PYTHON)

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I made the mistake of using permutations instead of combinations, i am supposed to print the names the user enters in this programs in pairs of two, not all the permutations of the names together, here is a snippet of my code, the full code can be found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/jvPZKdZ5) So the general question is instead of printing out every name combination possible, how can i print non repeated pairs of 2?

```
names = []

for i in range(n): names.append(raw_input("Enter name " + str(i + 1) + ": "))

count = 0


def perm(a, k=0):
global count
if (k == len(a)):
    print a

    count += 1
 else:
    for i in xrange(k, len(a)):
        a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]
        perm(a, k + 1)
        a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]


if n % 2 == 0:
print""
perm(names)
print"total combinations available: " + str(count)
else:

perm(names)
print"total combinations available: " + str(count)
print("please enter an even number next time")

sys.exit()
```

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations()` and `set()`.

Comment: @leaf how exactly would i go about with this? delete everything between  "for i" up to the "for" statement and replace it? sorry im really noobie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations()` to create all possible combinations, and then use `set()` to filter out all unique combinations:

```
import itertools
...
combinations = set(itertools.combinations(names, 2))
```

However, in your code it seems you only care about the ***number*** of possible combinations. You can use the builtin function `len()` to find this:

```
number_of_combinations = len(combinations)
```

Wherever you used `count` replace it with `number_of_combinations`.

Comment: My pleasure, @ethanjjjjjj.